# Setting an attribute of the Next.js response object

Tags: javascript, sockets, next.js

The question involves setting an attribute on the response object inside a Next.js API handler and also accessing that attribute later between requests. I didn't realize this was possible, and I couldn't find anything in the documentation or by searching online.

I'm looking at implementing [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) in a Next.js environment and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76277148/using-socket-io-with-next-js) question on StackOverflow. Here is the code snippet in question:

```js
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export default function SocketHandler(req, res) {
    if (res.socket.server.io) {
        console.log("Already set up");
        res.end();
        return;
    }
    const io = new Server(res.socket.server);
    ...
    res.socket.server.io = io;
    res.end();
}
```

As you can see the handler is checking for the existence of `res.socket.server.io`, which if found suggests that the socket is already set up. Later it sets `res.socket.server.io` to equal the newly created Server instance.

So do attributes on the `res` object get preserved between requests? And if so, what are the requirements for them to be preserved? Like I assume that it's per client.

Answer (score 2):

The provided code snippet utilized the `res.socket.server.io` attribute to store and access the Socket.io server instance. However, **this approach is incorrect** as the `res` object and its attributes are not preserved between requests in Next.js.

Here's why:

1. **Each request is independent:** In Next.js, each API request is treated as an isolated environment. This means any data or objects created within one request are not accessible in subsequent requests.
2. **"res" object is not persistent:** The `res` object is specific to each individual request and gets recreated for every new request. Modifying it within one request does not affect its state in other requests.

Here's the correct approach to handle Socket.io in a Next.js API route:

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export default function SocketHandler(req, res) {
  // Create a new Socket.io server instance for each request
  const io = new Server(res.socket.server);

  // Handle socket events and logic within this scope
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    // ...
  });

  res.end();
}
```